# $\partial^2_{\phi}f(\phi) +(A+B\phi+C\phi^2)f(\phi)=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the differential equation
$$
\partial^2_{\phi}f(\phi) +(A+B\phi+C\phi^2)f(\phi)=0
$$
where $A, B, C\in\mathbb{C}$ and $\phi\in[0,2\pi]$. I need the function to be antiperiodic, $f(\phi)=-f(\phi+2\pi)$. Under what conditions for $A,B,C$ does a solution exist? Is there a name for this family of differential equations. Are there analitical solutions?

Answer (score 2):

$$\partial^2_{\phi}f(\phi) +(A+B\phi+C\phi^2)f(\phi)=0$$
$$u'+u^2 =-(A+B\phi+C\phi^2)$$
Where $u=\dfrac {f'(\phi) }{f(\phi) }$.This is [Riccati's differential equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riccati_equation).
You can try a polynomial solution and play with it.
$$u=a_1\phi+a_2$$
Then you can find condtions on the coefficients for a closed form.